# How can I add different elements to a list in a list? Python 3

Tags: python, arrays, list, append

```
f = open("sonad.txt",encoding="utf-8")
c = f.readlines()
blokk = [[]] * 15
for read in c:
    length = len(read.strip())
    blokk[length].append(read.strip())
```

sonad.txt has just some random words and I would like to put them in an order like so:

All the words, that are 1 letter long go to blokk[1]
                        2 letters long go to blokk[2]
And so on...

But what my current code does is that it adds an element to allL block[x] so that
blokk[1] blokk[2] blokk[3] ..... are all the same.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The line `blokk = [[]] * 15` creates a list that has the *same empty list* in it 15 times.

You want to use a list comprehension instead:

```
blokk = [[] for _ in range(15)]
```

Try it out for yourself:

```
>>> blokk = [[]]*15
>>> blokk
[[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []]
>>> blokk[0].append(1)
>>> blokk
[[1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1]]
>>> blokk = [[] for _ in range(15)]
>>> blokk
[[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []]
>>> blokk[0].append(1)
>>> blokk
[[1], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []]
```

Comment: That is perfect! :) I didn't hope to get an answer within 3 minutes. Wow, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

```
 blokk = [[]]*15
```

creates 15 references to *the same list*.  So, if you append to `blokk[0]` or `block[1]`, those changes will be reflected in either list since they're the same list.

Perhaps a better data structure here is a `defaultdict`:

```
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(list)
with open('sonad.txt', encoding='utf-8') as fin:
    for line in fin:
        stripped = line.strip()
        d[len(stripped)].append(stripped)

print(sorted(d.items()))
```

Comment: @lazyr -- Thanks for the cleanup.  Apparently I was trying to be too hasty (but I had to be to beat Martijn ;).